# Define email environment-specific email settings?

Tags: plugin-development, emails

I'd like to define the SMTP server deets in my local config as I regularly need to push/pull databases between environments and will have different settings.

There doesn't seem to be any of doing this currently. Are there any workarounds? I thought maybe I could just put the SMTP deets in my code (testing for current enviroment) but the EmailModel class doesn't accept any of the SMTP-related properties of PHPMailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently email settings aren't multi-environment aware, so there is no native way to do this.

Probably worth adding to the [feedback](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com) site, as this has come up before, though.

Comment: Ok thanks. I would add feedback but I've run out of feedback credits!

Comment: Just checked and I must have earned some credits—have posted feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: We've written a plugin that automatically updates your email settings depending on your environment. It's not free, but it is cheap :-) Please [check out](http://red-robot.co.uk/our-work/email-settings-craft-cms-plug-in) the page on our website for more information.